# How do I change the blue borders in VS 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I imported my old fonts and colors settings under environment, and my code looks the way I like it, but I don't see where to change the look of the blue border surrounding it.

If anyone knows where this is, please help me complete my usual post-install pimp my IDE routine...

Comment: Hey, post some screenshots to your setup, I'm interested since I just installed VS2010.

Comment: Isn't this a superuser.com kind of question?

Answer (score 1):

Install the Visual Studio Color Theme Editor:
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/20cd93a2-c435-4d00-a797-499f16402378

Comment: Although this is an editor, it includes presets that'll do what you want immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot - there simply isnt any support for that. As MicTech said, this might appear in teh next version, or perhaps even the next SP for VS2010. Why? because it's not that hard, now that they've rewritten it in WPF (its not the WPF that makes it easier, its the rewritten architecture).